# How to insert only a few columns from a csv into a table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, csv, rails-activerecord

I have a large .csv file with the following header row:

```
:headers => 
     ["_id_", "name", "ascii_names", "alternate_name", "latitute",
     "longitude", "feature_class", "feature_code", "country_code", "cc2", 
     "admin_code_1", "admin_code_2", "admin_code_3", "admin_code_4", "population", 
     "elevation", "dem", "timezone", "modification_date"]}
```

I have a table only with the `name, country_code, timezone` columns in it.
I would like to insert only those 3 columns of the .csv file into the table.

What I've tried:

```
CSV.foreach(csv_file, {:col_sep => "\t", :quote_char => '&', :write_headers => true, :headers => ["_id_", "name", "ascii_names", "alternate_name", "latitute", "longitude", "feature_class", "feature_code", "country_code", "cc2", "admin_code_1", "admin_code_2", "admin_code_3", "admin_code_4", "population", "elevation", "dem", "timezone", "modification_date"]}
    ) do |row|
    City.create row.to_hash.values_at(:name, :timezone, :country_code)
    binding.pry
  end
```

The problem is that when I check the table after running this, none of the values are populated. The rows themselves have been created, but they're all empty.

How do I map these correctly, so that the `.create()` knows which columns match to the table?

Comment: I recommend loading files into a table with all the columns (as strings) and all the rows.  Then, insert from the staging table into the final table.

Comment: That seems very inefficient, and a completely indirect way of handling this. Why do you recommend that?

Comment: . . Because it gives you the best control over any errors that might happen.  When inserting data from a text file, errors are not uncommon, and having a way to handle the errors is more important than some minor efficiency in bringing the data in.

Comment: @GordonLinoff: I'd agree with you in general (or if this was my app and database) but we're talking Rails here and that means that all the columns probably allow NULLs, there's probably nothing in the database to maintain data consistency and correctness, there's probably a bunch of data logic outside the database, and there's probably no way to check anything inside the database because all that's supposed to be handled by Ruby code. On the upside, Rails4 has finally discovered foreign keys so there is some hope.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to first pick whether you're going to identify column headers as strings or symbols. In your `headers => ["_id_" ...]` you're declaring them as `Strings`, but in your `row.to_hash.values_at(:name, ...)`, you're looking for `Symbols`. -Thank you to @mu

Secondly, you can manually specify values to insert into your table without hashing them, as you can when you create new entries any other time through Ruby.

```
City.create(:name => row[:name], :timezone => row[:timezone], :country_code => row[:country_code])
```

All in all, your method should look like this:

```
  CSV.foreach(csv_file, {:col_sep => "\t", :quote_char => '&', #:write_headers => true, 
    :headers => [:geonameid, :name, :ascii_names, :alternate_name, :latitute, :longitude, :feature_class, :feature_code, :country_code, :cc2, :admin_code_1, :admin_code_2, :admin_code_3, :admin_code_4, :population, :elevation, :dem, :timezone, :modification_date]}
    ) do |row|
    City.create(:name => row[:name], :timezone => row[:timezone], :country_code => row[:country_code])
  end
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you're tell CSV that the headers are strings:

```
:headers => ["_id_", "name", ...]
```

That means that inside the `CSV.foreach` block, this:

```
row.to_hash
```

is a `Hash` with `String` keys. Then you call `values_at` on that `Hash` and ask for three `Symbol` keys and `values_at` is correctly giving you `[nil]` because a `Hash` with string keys won't have any values for `Symbol` keys. That means that you're `CSV.foreach` block is just an overly complicated way of saying:

```
City.create [nil]
```

When you pass an `Array` to [`create`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence/ClassMethods.html#method-i-create), you're essentially saying:

```
array.map { |e| City.create(e) }
```

That reduces your block to:

```
City.create nil
```

Somewhere inside ActiveRecord or ActiveModel it probably calling `to_h` on the passed attributes so calling `create` with `nil` is the same as calling it with an empty `Hash`.

The result of all that is a pile of empty records because, well, that's what you're asking ActiveRecord to do and you're not stopping it from throwing garbage data into your database.

The solution has two parts:

1. Use `String` keys everywhere or `Symbol` keys everywhere.
2. `create` wants a `Hash` argument in your case so use `Hash#slice` instead of `values_at`.

Something more like this:

```
CSV.foreach(csv_file, ...) do |row|
  City.create row.to_hash.slice(*%w[name timezone country_code])
end
```

---

PS: You really should include some `NOT NULL` constraints in your database and some validations in your models.